# FirebaseMessagingService extended class not calling onMessageReceived

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have problems with this class. I used fcm and I'm trying to handle notification. I send notification, and I recive it, but I cannot change anything, and if I delete some line, it still works.. Also, when I put some break points or when I want to write something in Log it's not working. 
In Body I send some name and I added ID. For example "Nike45", in code I tried to get that number, and I need it for extra in Intent.
But it's not working.. I added lines in gradle and in manifest.

```
package com.ekatalog.miki.katalozi1;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * Created by Miki on 2/15/2018.
 */

public class FcmMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {



@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
    String message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
    final Pattern lastIntPattern = Pattern.compile("[^0-9]+([0-9]+)$");
    String input = message;
    Matcher matcher = lastIntPattern.matcher(input);
    int lastNumberInt = 0;
    if (matcher.find()) {
        String someNumberStr = matcher.group(1);
        lastNumberInt = Integer.parseInt(someNumberStr);
    }

    message = message.replaceAll("\\d","");


    Intent intent = new Intent(this, KatalogOpend.class);
    intent.putExtra("KatalogID", lastNumberInt);
  //  Log.e("resr", message);
    //Log.e("rererer", String.valueOf(lastNumberInt));
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 ,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
    notificationBuilder.setContentText(message);
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.application_logo);
    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    notificationBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);
    notificationBuilder.setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 });

    //LED
    notificationBuilder.setLights(Color.RED, 3000, 3000);

    //Ton
   // notificationBuilder.setSound(Uri.parse("uri://sadfasdfasdf.mp3"));
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}
}
```

Comment: And have you mentioned this class as a receiver in manifest file?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is alright, just make sure you are sending a message payload not just a notification from Firebase because `onMessageRecieved` is only triggered when there is a message payload and will never trigger if it's a normal notification.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you handle the Notification and Data payload correctly, may be your missing out the data payload.Try below code once,

```
 @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        if (remoteMessage == null)
            return;

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Data Payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
                handleDataMessage(json);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

This might help you with more information, 
[About FCM Messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options)

Comment: When I try to debug it, I cannot handle this always. When I caught it, I got correct notification, but when I cannot handle it, I got notification with text+number...

Comment: Did you use handleIntent() it works always even if app is in foreground.

Comment: Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras(); if(bundle!=null) { for (String key : bundle.keySet()) { Object value = bundle.get(key); Log.d("DATA_SENT", String.format("%s %s (%s)", key, value.toString(), value.getClass().getName())); } }